# How do I get the last part of a url in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with a column of data in the format: http://www.website.com/stuff/more_stuff/part_i_want . How do I update all data in that format to only have the last part of the url (after the last '/')?

For example:
http://www.website.com/stuff/more_stuff/part_i_want -> part_i_want

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
db.table.aggregate([
    { $project : { $split: ["url", "/"] }, qty : 1 } }
])

db.table.update([ 
    {$set : { "url" : "url [ url.length - 1 ] } }
])
```

This is my first time using mongodb, so I have no idea if the syntax is even close to being correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to get the list of wanted parts, and do whatever you'd like with them, here I've inserted them into another table as you suggested;

```
db.table.aggregate([
  { $project : { item : { $split: ["$item", "/"] }, _id : 0 } }
]).map(obj => obj.item[obj.item.length - 1])
.forEach(result => db.table2.insert({wanted: result})
```

Then;

```
db.table2.find({}, {_id: 0})
```

returns

```
{"wanted": "part_i_want"}
{"wanted": "part_i_want2"}
```

for data;

```
db.table.insert([
  { item: "http://www.website.com/stuff/more_stuff/part_i_want"},
  { item: "http://www.website.com/stuff/more_stuff/part_i_want2"}
]);
```

Tested on the online console [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Also you can read more about these JavaScript on MongoDB cursors [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/#js-query-cursor-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an aggregation with a single [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage using [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) to generate the array delimited by `/` and take the last element with [`arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) :

```
db.table.aggregate(
    [{
        $project: {
            url: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$url", "/"] }, -1]
            }
        },
    }]
)
```

The aggregation can output the results to a temporary collection with [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) and be followed by a [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) to update all fields from the temporary collection into the initial collection :

```
var bulk = db.table.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()

query = [{
    $project: {
        url: {
            $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$url", "/"] }, -1]
        }
    },
}, {
    $out: "tempo"
}];

db.table.aggregate(query);

var bulkOps = db.tempo.find().map(function(doc) {
    return {
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "url": doc.url } }
        }
    };
});

db.table.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
```